# macbook pro mid 2012 won't start

Tags: power

I bought a secondhand macbook pro mid 2012 without retina and it has faulty battery. So I have to use 3 pin adapter.

Yesterday, it was okay (able to turn on, browse internet) yesterday and when I got home, I got statics (when I touched it, I feels like getting electric shock) when I plugged it in to power extension cord at my living room. After I tried on a few sockets, it still gave me statics but able to be turned on. I just unplugged it without properly shut down.

Today I tried on power on same living room and it still gives statics with a plus that it cannot turn on again.

I tried upstairs, no statics, but it won't turn on.

Before I bring it to a mac store which would cost a bomb (please not that one USD is at least 4.4 times MYR here in Malaysia), what should I try first?

I'm not sure of it's exact model since I only got macbook and magsage with it when I bought it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an edit link below it) to clarify your issue: (1) What do you meany by _statics_? (2) Does anything appear on the screen (error message, image, etc)? (3) When you say _it was okay yesterday_, do you mean it booted up fine and you were able to use it? (4) Can you add the exact model and specs.

Comment: Apparently, I did not know that power cord into macbook need to point outwards, not inwards in regards to its cable position. Well, new things every day.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a comment to your question seeking some clarification on your issue.

However, in the meantime, I'd reset both the NVRAM and SMC again (and in that order) using the steps below.

Before doing so, ensure you have no external hardware connected and that you're using the **built-in keyboard**.

**Reset the NVRAM**

Reset the NVRAM on your particular MBP following these steps:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

**Reset the SMC**

To reset the SMC on your particular MBP, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your computer
2. Keep the power cable **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the **left** side of the built-in keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

After resetting both the NVRAM and SMC, what happens? Does the issue still persist? If so, see if you can test your hardware as follows.

**Run Apple Hardware Test**

Your model MBP uses Apple Hardware Test. To use this, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your MacBook Pro
2. Restart your MacBook Pro
3. Press and hold the <kbd>D</kbd> key before the gray startup screen appears.
4. After a while, Apple Hardware Test (AHT) will start.
5. When prompted, select your language and click the right arrow.
6. When the AHT console appears, you can choose to run Basic tests by clicking the Test button. However, I suggest you select the "Perform extended testing" checkbox before you click the Test button.
7. Your test results will appear in the window in the bottom-right of the console.

**Note 1:** that the extended test will take some time. Take a note of the results and report back.

**Note 2:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Let me know if you can actually reset the NVRAM and SMC and test the hardware.